# angular datepicker and date format

Tags: angular, date, datepicker

i have some trouble properly using date with angular5

i fetch data from a mocked api where date is generated like that :
24/07/2018 00:00:00 
so there is no problem with resarch or anything manipulating those dates.

sample of the generation in api mock :

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_POLICIES; i++)
            {
                Policy lPolicy = new Policy { Id = i, Name = string.Concat("Policy number ", i), Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i) };

                p.Add(lPolicy);
            }
```

problem comes when i update dates with angular material DatePicker component.

with the picker, date shows up like tis :

```
Mon Jul 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

so when i update the item, date is passed like this :

```
updated item: {"id":1,"name":"Policy number 1","date":"2018-07-29T22:00:00.000Z"}
```

any idea how to deal with locales ?

EDIT :

Here is the problem when i do some research :

[image]

Comment: use angular filter

Comment: how you want the date to be displayed ? what's the format you want ?

Comment: helle @SaurabhAgrawal, do you mean filters like {{ today | date }}? if so, it's okay for displaying the date, but not to manipulate it :/ for example, if i update the date to 31/07/2018, it will be corretly displayed in browser, but if i use the "search" bar looking 31/07/2018, i dont get the item. to get it i have to search for 30/07/2018 even if displayed at 31/07/2018

Comment: you can inject the DatePipe into your component and use it to manipulate date as you want

Comment: i just edited my post so you can actually see the result : policy1 and 2 have been updated with DatePicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**DatePipe**](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) in the component itself, and format the date using [**pre-defined-format-options**](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options)

Try this

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

class Service {    
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}    
  changeDate(date) {
    return this.datePipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  }
}
```

Or you can format date like this as well

```
var formatted = new DatePipe().transform(raw, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: Mh, i've have an issue trying to inject the DatePipe in constructor. i get the following error : `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DatePipe]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DatePipe]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePipe!`

Comment: Nice, it seems to work ! thanks @Saurabh ! but it means that i have to manually pass the local into the pipe, right? like : `const formatted = new DatePipe('en-EN').transform(p.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');` so what about internationalization?

Comment: @j0w try this doc https://angular.io/guide/i18n.. Hope it will help you.

Comment: i sure will! :) if you could just tell me if the answer i posted is also a viable solution, and why i should use one over the other, that would help me a lot! thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Sure i will just give me sometime. I like the way dedicated you are.. Tomorrow I will answer you this one.

Comment: well, i'm new to angular, angular mat and typescript so, any advice on best practice is good to take :) Again, thanks your time!

Answer (score 1):

use moment for date and time, which gives the necessary formats.

https://momentjs.com/

momentjs have different properties to get the time and date in necessary format.

newDate = this.Today

date = moment(this.newDate)

you can also pass necessary formats like

date = moment(this.newDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')

Answer (score 0):

```
 const offset = p.date.getTimezoneOffset();
 const test = p.date.setMinutes(p.date.getMinutes() - offset);
```

console.log(test) returns :

```
updated item: {"id":1,"name":"Policy number 1","date":"2018-07-31T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

it works too but, is that "clean"?